# Estimating Parameters using MLE

Tags: r

I am new to R and I have been struggling on this for a while. I have a set of 611 data points, and I am trying to estimate its parameters (using MLE) to see if the data comes from a gamma distribution. I would then like to eventually plug the parameters found into a gamma model to then generate a density plot. 
So far, I have

```
     library(MASS)
     fitdistr(fireloss, "gamma")
     #outputs
     shape           rate    
     2.861599e+00   1.963065e-03 
     (1.116362e-01) (7.202933e-05)
```

I am unsure how to interpret the output. How would these parameters be plugged into a gamma model to generate a density plot? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to draw fitted graph and actual graph of gamma distribution in one plot?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/190465/how-to-draw-fitted-graph-and-actual-graph-of-gamma-distribution-in-one-plot)

Answer (score 3):

The output gives you the shape and rate parameter of the gamma distribution; you can find [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Characterization_using_shape_.CE.B1_and_rate_.CE.B2) the formula for the shape-rate parametrization.

To plot the probability density function you can just plug the values you obtained in the `dgamma` function. (I have also generated some data for adding them in the plot as histogram).

```
shape <- 2.861599e+00  # these are your estimated parameters 
rate <- 1.963065e-03 

y <- rgamma(611, shape = shape, rate = rate) # some random data
x <- seq(0, 6000, length.out=300)

hist(y, breaks = 30, freq = F)
lines(x, dgamma(x, shape = shape, rate = rate), type = "l", col = "blue", lwd = 2)
```

[image: Histogram with fit Gamma PDF Overlayed]