# Weibull distribution fit

Tags: fitting, weibull-distribution

I have a random variable $X$ for which it is known *a priori* that $P(X > x) = \exp(-ax^b)$, i.e. the CDF is given by $F_X(x) = 1-\exp(-ax^b)$.

I would like to determine the values of $a$ and $b$ but I am currently struggling to find an appropriate transformation of this "exponential-power" distribution that would allow me using the fitting functions with standard distributions.

Would you have any idea of transformation (or any alternative) that would help this purpose?

Edit: As indicated by the valuable comments, I was indeed looking for a Weibull distribution. 
I tried fo fit this model using *fitdist* in R. The results are shown on the figure. [image: Weibull fitting]

At first glance, it looks pretty satisfying (except for the tail on the Q-Q plot). However, the Kolmogorov-Smirnov goodness of fit test dramatically fails (p-value < 1e-14). Should I reject the model based on the KS test results?

Comment: Would you please post a link to the data?

Comment: @user158565 - It's a Weibull distribution.  $F_X(0) = 0$.

Comment: What language are you working with?  It makes a difference, as "fitting functions with standard distributions" is a language-specific reference, and your distribution is one of the standard ones (the Weibull.)

Comment: @user158565 - $\exp\{-(ax)^n\} = \exp\{-bx^n\}$, where $b = a^n$.  $1 - \exp\{-a0^n\} = 1-\exp\{-0\} = 0$.

Comment: @jbowman Sorry. Something is wrong with me. basically I switched $x^n$ and $n^x$.

Comment: @user158565 - Ha ha! It's happened to me before too, no worries :). Funny how our minds fail us sometimes...

Comment: @jbowman I thought I was the only one who did that.

Comment: Many of the ideas in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/111010/interpreting-qqplot-is-there-any-rule-of-thumb-to-decide-for-non-normality carry over to this thread. Tests are of very limited use here, especially with large sample sizes. The conclusion "this distribution isn't perfectly fit by a Weibull" is neither surprising nor constructive. Reject Weibull if and only if you can find a better fitting distribution.