# Nonparametric way to perform ANOVA of linear mixed model for small sample and power calculation

Tags: r, mixed-model, anova, nonparametric, bootstrap

I have a small data where there are 3 groups (A,B,C) and 5 participants from each group. All of those participants are measured 6 times on each of 7 different exams, so each participant get 6*7=42 scores in total. A simple linear mixed model was built `mylmm<-lmer(score ~1+group+exam+group*exam+(1|participant), data = mydata)`. I could obtain the anova results and post-hoc pairwise comparison for group, exam, and interaction of them using `anova(mylmm)` and multiple comparison function.

However, the data is very small (only 5 participants) and residual of mylmm is not normal, so the power is insufficient. The score is continuous and I really need to keep it in the original scale if possible (but tranformations including box-cox don't work). I am aware of robust mixed model using `robustlmm` and residual bootstrap mixed model using `lmeresampler`. However, I am unable to perform anova and multiple comparisons using these packages. Could anyone help me with the following questions? It is really appreciated.

1. Is there a method and available R package to perform bootstrap anova (and post-hoc comparisons) of linear mixed model?
2. Is it still necessary to calculate the power of the bootstrap or nonparametric anova? If so, how to calculate the power?
3. I am also aware of aligned ranks transformation ANOVA. Does this method work here and especially for small data? Also, how can I calculate for the power?
4. There is also another related but not so important question. For the model built directly from `lme` (without bootstrapping), I was able to use `simr` with methods anova to calculate power of testing group, exam, and the interaction. Can `simr` also be used to find power of post hoc pairwise comparisons? Thanks.

Comment: When you say the residuals are not normal, are you referring to the within-participant residuals? Can you show us the graph from `lattice::qqmath(mylmm)`? Also see this handy thread about residuals. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/111010/interpreting-qqplot-is-there-any-rule-of-thumb-to-decide-for-non-normality/111013#111013

Answer (score 4):

Aligned-rank nonparametric procedures are essentially ad hoc.  I suggest using a random effects semiparametric ordinal regression model such as the proportional odds model.  The R `ordinal` package will do this.  To accurately handle the random effects take care to not use the default numerical integration procedure, as briefly discussed [here](https://hbiostat.org/bbr/nonpar#sec-nonpar-pairmodel).  See [here](https://fharrell.com/post/rpo) for resources for ordinal regression.  The proportional odds model generalizes the Wilcoxon and Kruskal-Wallis tests.

Note that a Bayesian proportional odds model will provide even more accurate inference due to not using numerical integration approximations.

Comment: Thank you @FrankHarrell. Sorry it wasn't so clear. The score is not ordinal but continuous and I need to interpret the results in the original scale.

Comment: With ordinal regression you can restate the results on any scale, e.g., get estimated medians and means.  Examples are [here](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/cony).  Ordinal regression works great for continuous Y.