# How do I claim this set of data follows an exponential distribution?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, goodness-of-fit, fitting, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I have a set of data that has following histogram:

[image]

I would like to guess it follows an exponential distribution. So I did some goodness of fit using KS test with MATLAB like following:

```
%% first load the data
fileID = fopen('data.dat','r')
dct= fread(fileID,'float');
fclose(fileID);

%% do distribution fitting
pd = fitdist(dct(:),'Exponential');

%% do ks test
test_cdf = makedist('exp', 'mu',  pd.mu);
[h, p] = kstest(dct(:), 'CDF', test_cdf);
```

However, I got

```
h =
     1

p =
     0
```

which means the hypothesis that my data follows an exponential is rejected.

I am wondering where I got wrong? Or how can I confirm the data I have follows an exponential distribution? Thanks a lot. I am attaching the original data here.

[data.dat](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7949206/data.txt)

Comment: Try `histogram(log10(dct),100)`. There are a whole bunch of values around 4e-11, 6e-10, 2.5e-9 etc...  It doesn't look exponential.

Comment: @MatthewGunn I seem not to have histogram() function built in my MATLAB. Mine is 2014.

Comment: use `hist` then. Some other ideas: (1) `x = sort(dct)` and then inspect `x` by hand.  (2) A tool for comparing distributions you should be aware of is [qqplot](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/101274/how-to-interpret-a-qq-plot).