# Half-Normal plot of residuals interpretation

Tags: self-study, data-visualization, residuals, model, qq-plot

I fitted a regression model and getting trouble to interpret the Half-Normal plot of Pearson and Deviance residuals.
[image]

[image]

In general the fit looks good because the residuals are inside the confidence bands. But what more I can say?

I read this topic [How to interpret a QQ plot](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/101274/how-to-interpret-a-qq-plot) but not sure if the interpretation is the same for Half-Normal.

Comment: Is this from "binomTools" or something else?

Comment: @Glen_b I did it at "hand" from a JAGS output

Comment: How did you compute the curve in the second plot? Is that from some form of bootstrapping/simulation or some theoretical calculation?

Comment: @Glen_b The confidence bands are made from simulations.

Comment: Thanks; I was asking about the curve in between -- presumably that's also simulation?

Comment: @Glen_b Yeah it's also simulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. When looking at regression diagnostics, reading a half-normal plot of residuals is fairly similar to reading the top half of a Q-Q plot of residuals, at least when identifying lighter or heavier tails than anticipated. However if one tail is lighter and the other heavier, that may be less easy to identify in a half-normal plot (though *much* more or less skewness than expected will still show up as a wiggle)

   (Half normal plots are sometimes used on estimated *effects* to identify "important" effects from "unimportant"; that doesn't seem to be what you have here)
2. In a GLM of course you don't expect the residuals to be actually normal unless the family was normal. The deviance residuals plot you show, where the expected "line" is actually a curve may be a little harder to judge; at least you have the "curve" to help you.