# How would you judge this qq plot? Distributional assumptions? Outliers?

Tags: qq-plot

Looking for some help. Here's my qq plot. I already deleted the most extreme outliers, but some remain. Also, what about the distributional assumption?

[image]

Comment: Seems like you are dealing with a fat tailed distribution. Note that for such distribution the statistical properties are much worse.

Comment: Without some hint of what's on what axis this plot isn't much use

Answer (score 1):

I would say it fails to meet normality assumptions because of its divergence at the tails. However, you could use something like an Anderson-Darling test to test for normality more precisely. You can not particularly assume outliers from the qqplot -- but just that some points fray from a normal distribution.

As @Dole noted, you have fat tails and your data could be a t-distribution.

I would also check out this wonderful answer for further qq plot questions: [How to interpret a QQ plot](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/101274/how-to-interpret-a-qq-plot?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: There just as easily could be *short* tails: it all depends on what the axes mean.  I believe we can figure out which axis is which, but that merits some explanation.