# QQ Plot Interpretaion

Tags: r, data-visualization, normal-distribution, quantiles

I have a daily time series and when trying to check for normality I am getting the QQ plot below. Any ideas as to what is the plot saying about my data?

[image: Data QQ Plot]

Comment: What do you think it thinks?  Have you read about qqplot documentation?  Have you looked at examples?  What questions are you bringing?  What would you do with an answer if you found it?  also I like "qqPlot" over "qqnorm".  It is a different library and has the upper and lower confidence intervals for each quantile.

Comment: Take a look at this site, there's good stuff that could help you to answer your question. For example, you can refer to this post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/101274/how-to-interpret-a-qq-plot

Comment: Clearly, your data takes on discrete values. You might learn more with `table(x)` or `hist(x)` than you do with qqnorm.

Comment: Think what would make this closer to normal. Some counts of -1, -2, -3. ...?