# How do I interpret this plot?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, skewness, qq-plot, bimodal

[image: qqplot]I'm finding it hard to interpret this plot. Is it skewed, bimodal, or what is it? What do the points lying in the same line and rising suddenly mean? Is it exponential?

Comment: Points lying in the same horizontal line say that all those observations were equal - in your chart more than half the observations seem to have taken the minimum value

Comment: The top part of [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/101290/805) answer explicitly addresses the flat and steeply rising parts. (Indeed with a discrete variable like that, you nearly have a stacked stripchart on its side, albeit not "lined up", so that one's pretty easy to read)

Comment: Compare with a table and a histogram or dot plot (strip plot, many other names) and relate to the definition of the variable/ Why so many at 5? Is there an upper limit in principle?

Comment: This is what *left-censored* data would like like when drawn from an approximately Normal distribution and all values less than $5$ were coded as $5.$