Normality assumption - qqplot interpretation
I am currently working on a project that involves evaluating the distribution of several variables, and I am using Q-Q plots as part of the analysis. While I have generated the Q-Q plots for these variables. It's true I have been working with these a long time but still I want to listen to opinions here. The sample size of these variables are close to 70, and the purpose is to perform independent t-tests among several variables as long as longitudinal analysis. I can advance that shapiro and ks-test reject normality assumption.
I would greatly appreciate your guidance in interpreting them accurately to assess normality and identify any deviations from gaussian distribution. These biomarkers usually get heavier in the tails, but I wouldn't go for transformations.Any comment is welcome!
Edit: as you can see I have 3 measurements of the variables. As I told before, my main plan is to compare 2-sample test (_v00 compared to _v66, and _v66 with _v01), but I was focused on the normality assumption.










I''m not sure I understand the overall goal of your analysis, but the three plots you show indicate heavier tails than a Normal distribution.

Thank you for the comment. The idea is to compare these variables in different groups, using an independent sample t.test, but also modeling in longitudinal model.

possibly duplicated: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/101274/how-to-interpret-a-qq-plot

Why not use regression?

I am comparing just independent samples. Not response variable. In fact they are the response variable in further longitudinal analysis

What is your question?  I don't see a "?" anywhere.  Also, please add a lot more information about your situation, your data, & your goals.

You should be aware that it isn't clear either current answer is what you need.  Without more information it is quite likely that peoples' guesses will be off and neither you nor they will realize it.

@gung-ReinstateMonica  mygoal is to ask about normality assessment. I might be incorrect in focusing primarily on the use of QQ plots, which are commonly seen and widely used for this purpose. However, if this approach is insufficient or flawed, I would greatly appreciate it if you could explain why, perhaps with an example or a suggestion for alternative methods to better understand normality.

What exactly do you want to ask about normality assessment?  I still don't see a "?" anywhere.  Is your question simply, 'are qq-plots acceptable as a means to assess normality?'  Is your question, 'are these variables normally distributed?'  Is it, 'are these normal enough for something?' (what?)  Moreover, what are these variables?  What is the point of your study?  Etc.

Generally model assumptions are never precisely fulfilled, as models are thought constructs, and reality is generally more complicated. The t-test is approximately correct for large enough samples with many non-normal distributions, but there are problematic situations such as with extreme outliers.
Looking at your plots, the involved distributions look heavy-tailed, i.e., extreme observations occur with somewhat larger probability that under the normal. However, they look roughly symmetric (which is good), and normality is not violated by one or a few really extreme outliers, rather we have gradually heavier tails on both sides without gross outliers. With $n=70$ chances are the t-test will have characteristics very close to if the underlying distribution were normal, i.e., it should be OK to use. Chances are the rejection probability under what I call "interpretative null hypothesis" (non-normal but with mean corresponding to the normal null hypothesis) will be a little bit lower than the test level $\alpha$ (which is not bad), and the power may suffer a bit. It will depend on the situation, but if you can live with the odd type II error you should be fine.
Alternatively you could consider a Wilcoxon signed rank test (assuming you run one-sample tests). It is hard to say whether that will be better, and I suspect in the given situation it may have about the same quality as the t-test (it may however be a better sell if your audience thinks that you shouldn't use a t-test if data are not normal).
However I understand that these are some exemplary plots, and of course my answer relies on everything that is relevant (including what we don't see) looking more or less like these.

A few comments\thoughts.

Your data is definitively not normal; no wonder normality tests rejected normality. And indeed, they have heavier tails than a Gaussian. But it looks nicely symmetric, which is good (now, of course, this is based on the 3 samples you shared; are all of them that nicely symmetric?). You say you want to use "independent t-tests". I assume therefore 2-sample t-tests. In that case it is not the 2 original distributions which need to be normal, but the sampling distribution of the difference of the means, for which you have only a single observation. But if you have single humped, symmetric original distributions, the CLT will converge much faster than most people realize, often with single digit sample sizes. In your case (one hump, symmetric), with sample sizes around 70, I would not worry at all about non-normality; the CLT is your "get out of jail free card".
I would use a Welch t-test, as, per the Q-Q plots, the variances seem different (? again, based on only the 3 graphs). That will avoid any issue with unequal variances/unequal sample sizes.
If you are still really worried about non-normality (or your reviewers/supervisor really are), a previous answer mentioned a Wilcoxon Sign Rank test (WSRt). But that is for only a single sample (or paired samples), which does not seem to be your case. But instead you could use Mood's median test, which is a true median test (WSRt is a test of the pseudo-median), and is basically a binomial test. With sample sizes around 70, it should have decent power. Alternatively, you could use a Brunner Munzel test (BMt), which is a non-parametric test equivalent to the  Mann Whitney U test (test of stochastic equality), but w/o the Behrens Fisher problem (just like the Welch t test solves the Behrens Fisher problem for the Student's t test).
In fact, I would most likely run t-tests, median tests, and BMts, just to make sure that they give similar results. If the answers are different, particularly if they are in different directions (i.e. $A>B$ for one test, but $B>A$ for another), then summarizing differences as just differences of locations (as t-test or median tests do) is an oversimplification. The differences in distribution are more complex, involving shape, and I would have to look at each case by case. But if I did do not observe any "contradiction", I would feel much more confident in the results, and would pick a single test to make my point (and just note, maybe in a footnote, that the other 2 tests confirmed the findings).


Thank you for the elaborated response. As you said I want to perform 2-sample t-test, not paired, just comparing 2 groups. I will look into the BMt. Regarding the sample size, I've perceived by your comment, an approximation of convergence, easier due to n = 70. Is it just a mental estimation?

If you read textbooks etc., the most common number you will see is 30. Why, where does it come from? I do not know, and I doubt anyone truly knows. The best way to build an intition is to run simulations. Try a one-hump, symmetric-ish distribution, e.g. a $\chi^2$ with not too low a df (e.g. df=5, which is actually quite skewed), and try sample sizes as low as e.g. 10; the sampling distribution of the mean will look pretty gaussin, gaussian enough for the t-test to provide very good results. Take a uniform distribution, and it converges with sample sizes as low as 5. ...ctd

...ctd. YOu may want to rread this blog https://miroslavtushev.medium.com/does-my-sample-have-to-be-normally-distributed-for-a-t-test-7ee91aaaca2a or this paper https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/11910059/, and these 2 links have nice simulations https://david-salazar.github.io/posts/fat-vs-thin-tails/2020-05-30-central-limit-theorem-in-action.html https://www.lesswrong.com/posts/YM6Qgiz9RT7EmeFpp/how-long-does-it-take-to-become-gaussian. In your case, with 70 samples, you would need data with a much larger skew than what your q-q plots show to be still far from convergence at 70. ...ctd

...ctd. Assymetry + fat tail is the CLT's kryptonite (where you may need sample sizes of several 1000's). Your data (from what you have shown us) is much better behaved.
