# Does this P-P plot indicate a violation of the normality assumption?

Tags: regression, normality-assumption

I am testing the OLS assumptions and I got the following normal P-P plot.  Does it look normally distributed or not?

[image]

Comment: How many data points is that, 140? 150? How many predictors?

Answer (score 5):

This looks fine to me, as far as that goes.  What you are most concerned about is the tails of your distribution, and pp-plots don't show those very well.  QQ-plots do better; see: [PP-plots vs. QQ-plots](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/100383/7290).

Answer (score 0):

There are formal tests for normality- in particular the Jarque-Bera/Skewness-Kurtosis type tests.

Comment: Jarque-Bera as I have seen it implemented uses asymptotic results for every sample size, a very bad idea as the convergence of sample skewness and kurtosis to normality is very slow indeed.

Comment: is a K-S test better?

Comment: Not to me. Almost none of these tests can possibly compare with a Q-Q plot, which shows you how much and where data depart from normality. A K-S test is arguably most sensitive in the middle of the distribution, precisely where departures are least important. Cf. @gung's comments.