# QQ-Plots in Julia via Plots.jl?

Tags: qq-plot, julia

I am trying to make QQ-Plots in Julia, but the only solution I could find is [this old example using Gadfly](https://gist.github.com/kleinschmidt/7ce8cec988a84ce73ba2). Given that it's being deprecated, I wanted to know if anyone knew of a solution for making the QQ-plots in Plots.jl. Maybe there's a stats recipe for QQ-plots around? Or how would you make such a series recipe?

The problem can be boiled down to this: Given two arrays representing samples of distributions, how does transform this into the quantile-quantile information which is used in a qq-plot?

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here, but
you may have a real statistical question buried here. 
You may want to edit your question to clarify the underlying 
statistical issue. You may find that when you understand 
the statistical concepts involved, the software-specific elements are 
self-evident or at least easy to get from the documentation.

Comment: The problem is that there doesn't seem to be a software for it, so I'm asking how exactly one would make a stats recipe from two arrays representing samples of distributions to something which can be plotted as quantile-quantile.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking for code (which is off topic here). You could de-emphasize the software aspect & ask how it is done conceptually--that should be fine. However, note that how to construct a qq-plot has already been discussed elsewhere on the site (eg, here: [PP-plots vs. QQ-plots](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/100383/7290)), so this would probably still be a duplicate.

Comment: It seems that the link gave has enough information to answer my question. This may be marked as duplicate then.