# GLMM validation: weird qq & fit vs residual plots

Tags: r, mixed-model, glmm, validation, qq-plot

I'm encountering problems with the results of a `glmer` model (`lme4`-package).
Im trying to answer the question, whether a beaver is more likely to be present (`Status == 1`) or absent (`Status == 0`) with changing geomorphic and vegetation variables. My model formula looks like this:

```
model1 <- glmer(Status ~ SlopecatCentered + Canal_width + Distance:Resource_biotopes + 
                         (1 | Location), family="binomial", data=Daten12, 
                control=glmerControl(optimizer="Nelder_Mead"))
```

My output looks OK, as far as I can tell, the only peculiar thing being the high estimates of `slopecatCentered`:

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) 
  ['glmerMod']
Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: Status ~ SlopecatCentered + Canal_width + Distance:Resource_biotopes + 
                  (1 | Location)
Data: Datentest
Control: glmerControl(optimizer = "Nelder_Mead")

AIC      BIC     logLik    deviance   df.resid 
62.7     77.4    -25.3     50.7       80 

Scaled residuals: 
  Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-0.095917 -0.003971  0.000000  0.002706  0.079395 

Random effects:
Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
Location (Intercept) 3682     60.68   
Number of obs: 86, groups:  Location, 43

Fixed effects:
                            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                 -18.5782     7.0847  -2.622 0.008734 ** 
SlopecatCentered             20.4162     5.6060   3.642 0.000271 ***
Canal_width                   0.4763     0.1584   3.007 0.002638 ** 
Distance1:Resource_biotopes   1.0442     0.4717   2.214 0.026861 *  
Distance2:Resource_biotopes   1.0379     0.4662   2.226 0.026010 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) SlpctC Cnl_wd Ds1:R_
SlopctCntrd -0.632                     
Canal_width -0.902  0.698              
Dstnc1:Rsr_ -0.663  0.560  0.458       
Dstnc2:Rsr_ -0.677  0.538  0.461  0.787
```

My qqplot looks weird, though, and so does my residual vs. fitted plot:

[image: qqnorm plot with sjp.glmer(model,...)]

[image: fitted vs. residual plot using plot(model)]

edit: I just had a closer look on my data: The `SlopecatCentered`variable is not a perfect predictor, but my random factor `Location`is causing this problem. In my raw data set, it denotes 43 different locations. One location has two `distance` in which most of the variables were measured, so my `location`variable has 43 * 2 = 86 entrys (in fact, that's the length of the data frame):

```
 >Daten12$Loc
[1] 1  1  2  2  3  3  4  4  5  5  6  6  7  7  8  8  9  9  10 10 11 11 12 12 13 13 14 14 15 15 16 16 17
[34] 17 18 18 19 19 20 20 21 21 22 22 23 23 24 24 25 25 26 26 27 27 28 28 29 29 30 30 31 31 32 32 33 33
[67] 34 34 35 35 36 36 37 37 38 38 39 39 40 40 41 41 42 42 43 43
43 Levels: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 ... 43
```

I changed that to 1-86 and ran a test model and the plot looked ok (I know that the random effect was futile in that test model, but I wanted to get to the root of the problem).

So apparantly, my raw data frame layout is wrong. But I got samples online to compare, and their layout looks similar, so I just don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Much of what you want to know can be found in my answer here: [Interpretation of plot(glm.model)](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/139624/7290).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was helpful, indeed. Still, my plots seem to be worse than the ones in your example. I just can't imagine a natural way (especially for my random effects quantiles) to behave like they do.

Comment: The random effects are a distinct issue, or I would have closed this as a duplicate. But fitted vs residual won't typically 'look right' given that your response is binary.

Answer (score 2):

Without looking at your data, I'm guessing that you have complete separation on your response. An estimate of 20 on the logit scale is effectively infinity, and translates to fitted probabilities of zero or one. You might want to double-check your `SlopecatCentered` variable to make sure it's not related to the response somehow.

Comment: That's an interesting possibility, but the SEs aren't large & the p's are low. That isn't what you expect to see w/ separation.

Comment: @gung This is with `glmer` though, which does a regularized fit compared to regular maximum likelihood.

Comment: Also, note that the fitted values are indeed 0 and 1, from the graph.

Comment: Hmmm, good points.

Comment: Thanks. The `SlopecatCentered`variable measured the bank slope of all sampled `location`. It used to be in percentages, but was then converted into factors ranging from 1-5. After that it was scaled and centered, as R issued a warning about nearly unidentifiable coefficients and suggested to rescale.

Answer (score 0):

Apparantly the problem is the amount of factor levels of `location`. There are 43 locations but just 2 nested factor levels of the `distance` variable *within* `location`. I altered the data set as to have only a twentieth, a thenth, a fifth and half of the factor levels of `location`and recast the model after each alteration. I could see how the slope was generated with each addidtional factor level until it reached that "perfect plateau" - thing as shown in my first post. 
I have no idea how to solve this problem though...