# Improvement of Interpretation of residuals vs fitted plot

Tags: regression, data-visualization, dataset, residuals

I wish to examine assumptions for single regression using the built in diagnostics within R. The residuals vs fitted plot below seemly violated the assumption. There are 2 dummy coded variables within my model and 1 categorical variable (testing probability). The model only explains 8% of the variance in selection (DV).
What improvements/Advice can be tell from the plot? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: The definition residual $=$ observed $-$ fitted implies that distinct observed values define parallel lines on this plot, in this case residual $= 0\ -$ fitted and residual $= 1\ -$ fitted. Nothing is really violated here; it is just that your data aren't well suited to the model you fit.

Comment: For diagnosing a logistic regression, consider using DHARMa, see hints on logistic regression in https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DHARMa/vignettes/DHARMa.html#binomial-data

Answer (score 1):

Without wanting this to sound snotty, my advice would be not to use linear regression with a binary outcome variable.  Use [logistic](/questions/tagged/logistic) regression instead.  (In R, that's: `glm(<formula>, <data>, family=binomial)`.  When you do use logistic regression, ignore these plots (see my answer to: [Interpretation of plot (glm.model)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/139624/7290)).