# Generalised Linear Model (GLM) linearity assumption checking

Tags: generalized-linear-model, data-visualization, inference, residuals, assumptions

For GLM model, we have the linearity assumption that the transformed response variable (through) the link function) is linearly dependent on the variables. I'm checking this assumption using the Residuals vs Fitted plot (plot the Deviance residuals against the Transformed fitted value eta_i) and have the plot shown below.
I wonder if the plot below means that this linearity assumption is not valid?

[image]

Comment: Take a look at the R `DHARMa` package - it's really hard to assess GLM assumptions using this kind of residual plot. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DHARMa/vignettes/DHARMa.html

Answer (score 3):

It is best not to use those plots for non-OLS regression models (cf.: [Interpretation of plot (glm.model)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/139624/7290)).  If you want a *test* of the assumption of linearity (on the transformed scale), you can add polynomial or spline terms beyond the linear term and test them as a set.